# tracking a gps sticker on android

Tags: android, gps, tracking

I m going to explain simply what I want to do, and I will appreciate for your recommendation. I want to put a small gps sticker on my kid and develop an app in order to track him in real time, if he is going to school or not.

1. Is there any gps device (sticker) like that, if so can this device send its position simultaneously to my app.
2. Is there any tutorial that can help me to develop an app like this

Answer (score 0):

There are GPS devices available in market for spying. You don't have to develop an app as They will also provide an app. checkout on of the link

http://www.cheatersspyshop.com/gps-trackers.html

or simply search spy GPS on google you will find a list of devices.